# args.unshift(function replayOrFree(){...}) is that meaningful?

Tags: javascript

I see these code beblow, but cannot understand.I did some small test, and found out that `replayOrFree` function never invoked.
so, what these code mean?

```
var lock = function (func) {
    var locked, queuedArgsToReplay;

    return function () {
        // Convert arguments into a real array.
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
        if (locked) {
            // Keep a copy of this argument list to replay later.
            // OK to overwrite a previous value because we only replay
            // the last one.
            queuedArgsToReplay = args;
            return;
        }
        locked = true;
        var self = this;
        args.unshift(function replayOrFree() {
            if (queuedArgsToReplay) {
                // Other request(s) arrived while we were locked.
                // Now that the lock is becoming available, replay
                // the latest such request, then call back here to
                // unlock (or replay another request that arrived
                // while this one was in flight).
                var replayArgs = queuedArgsToReplay;
                queuedArgsToReplay = void 0;
                replayArgs.unshift(replayOrFree);
                func.apply(self, replayArgs);
            } else {
                locked = false;
            }
        });
        func.apply(this, args);
    };
};


 //....


    // Call the search method of selected strategy..
    _search: lock(function (free, strategy, term, match) {
        var self = this;
        strategy.search(term, function (data, stillSearching) {
            if (!self.dropdown.shown) {
                self.dropdown.activate();
                self.dropdown.setPosition(self.adapter.getCaretPosition());
            }
            if (self._clearAtNext) {
                // The first callback in the current lock.
                self.dropdown.clear();
                self._clearAtNext = false;
            }
            self.dropdown.render(self._zip(data, strategy));
            if (!stillSearching) {
                // The last callback in the current lock.
                free();
                self._clearAtNext = true; // Call dropdown.clear at the next time.
            }
        }, match);
    }),
```

Comment: source code : https://github.com/yuku-t/jquery-textcomplete/blob/master/src/completer.js

Answer (score 1):

The code that you have shared is of two parts.

The bottom part is about a function call that requires to be sequential. It means that as long the first function call has not returned the results, the second call to the same function cannot be made.

The top part is where this concurrency has been handled. The code in top part receives the function reference as a parameter, sets a blocking flag so that the another call to the same function does not pass through and later, after executing the function, the blocking flag is unset so the next call to the function could be executed just as first one.

Now expanding this description; If the first function call is still being executed and another function call is made, the blocking flag does not just reject the second call. It rather saves the "arguments" of the second call so that once the first function call is executed successfully, the later code can look to see if there are any arguments saved form the second function call or not. If there are, then these arguments are used to make the second function call.

Now the question arises that what if there was a third call to the same function while even the first function call has not returns the result? In this case, as per the code the arguments of the third call overwrites the arguments of the second function call. so when the first call finishes its work, it uses the arguments of third function call (which were overwritten to the variable saving the second function call to the same function).

Use case is what if you want to update chat status on a browser window and get the messages from the server. if you queue up all the api calls to be called in order then this will waste resources. so what you do is while one update is requested, you queue up the calls by saving only the last call made for the server.

PS: I would not suggest to use this code as its a bit error prone.

hope that helps.